# Setup SSL for Django with gunicorn on Debian 9 on Compute Engine

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, django-sslify

I am working on a project which has been deployed on compute engine on Debian 9 VM instance.

Here's are the steps I have performed:

1. Create Instance and ssh into
2. Install Python (3.6) directly by using these commands:

   - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
   - `sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev`
   - `sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm`
   - `sudo apt-get install -y libncurses5-dev  libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev`
   - `wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/Python-3.6.4.tgz`
   - `tar xvf Python-3.6.4.tgz`
     and some other build commands to ....
3. Then install virtualenv and activate it
4. Clone the django project from github and install the requirements
5. And run the gunicorn and the project is working fine.

But now, I want to set up the `ssl` for my Django projects, I have googled it but the tutorials are for nginx, I don't have setup nginx on my VM instance, so how can I set up SSL on my instance? I want to use `Lets Encrypt`.

Comment: so setup nginx. And you can include `Lets Encrypt` with it.

Comment: setup `nginx` by following this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 and include `lest encrypt` by following this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 It would work on Debian too.